# How to keep a users cart active after logout - Craft Commerce 2

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce2

How do I set the cart to save / stay active in a users account. When I add some products to my cart (when logged in) and logout or close my browser the next time I come back my cart is empty. I'd like to have the cart 'stay alive' until I complete the order. Help is appreciated!